# Flutter: setState() inside GestureDetector is not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

In my code I am loading network images into a grid. Then I allow the user to replace a network image by selecting one from their own gallery. Please check the below code.

```
Widget _buildPhotoSection() {
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
          ),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            XFile? imageFile;
            bool check = false;
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                final XFile? image =
                    await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                setState(() {
                  imageFile = image;
                  check = true;
                  print("DONE");
                });
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      child: check == false
                          ? index <= imageList.length - 1
                              ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 150,
                                  imageUrl: imageList[index].imageURL == ""
                                      ? "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-6.png"
                                      : imageList[index].imageURL,
                                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                )
                              : CachedNetworkImage(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 150,
                                  imageUrl:
                                      "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-6.png",
                                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                )
                          : Image.file(
                              File(imageFile!.path),
                              width: 200,
                              height: 150,
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            'Change',
                          )))
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

here I can pick the image but the image from gallery never get displayed. It looks like the `setState` was working even though it is called.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `XFile? imageFile;` is defined in `_buildPhotoSection` function - not in the widget itself. So you are practically updating local variable in setState() call. Once setState() finishes - it will notify Flutter engine to rebuild the widget - and your imageFile variable will be reinitialized - not holding the value you set in previous iteration.

I think you should just move `XFile? imageFile;`  and `bool check = false;` to class level, this should do the trick.

Edit: after your comment about multiple images - here's my suggestion:

```
var imageFile=<int, XFile>{};

Widget _buildPhotoSection() {
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
          ),
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
//             XFile? imageFile;
            //bool check = false;
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                final XFile? image =
                    await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

                setState(() {
                  imageFile[index] = image;
                  //check = true;
                  print("DONE");
                });
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      child: imageFile.containsKey(index) == false
                          ? index <= imageList.length - 1
                              ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 150,
                                  imageUrl: imageList[index].imageURL == ""
                                      ? "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-6.png"
                                      : imageList[index].imageURL,
                                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                )
                              : CachedNetworkImage(
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 150,
                                  imageUrl:
                                      "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-6.png",
                                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                )
                          : Image.file(
                              File(imageFile[index]!.path),
                              width: 200,
                              height: 150,
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            'Change',
                          )))
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

You will note that I converted imageFile to a map - that will hold an index and XFile that user selected. I also removed check variable - I'm checking if the Map contains the index key or not, and based on that the image should render.

I didn't try to compile this, so few errors might be inthere.

Comment: I cant do that. This is dynamic generation of images. I have 5 images and they are generated by a `Grid` builder. User may update one image or many, and the display image should get updated accordingly.

Comment: So you need a ````List<Xfile> imageFile```` - i.e. a list of images for your GridVeiw to show, and each onTap should replace one element of the list. But the principle is the same - you need your data on the class level - this is where you store your state and enable setState() to manipulate it.

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that works for you.